# I wanted to add lables and channels of an image seprately by myself?

Tags: python, image-processing, data-science, torch

**for performing linear regression i did torch.stack and torch.cat to every other the torch.cat operation it took me about 10 min so i wanted to konw an optimal approach  .**

```
from torch.utils.data import random_split // used random_split to 
                                                         split data

train_ds, val_ds = random_split(dataset,[50000,10000])
len(train_ds) , len(val_ds)

#linear regression self

d = [ ]
n = len(train_ds)
for i in range(0,n):
    label = train_ds[i][1]
    d.append(label)
    

a = train_ds[0][0]
b = train_ds[1][0]    
c = torch.stack((a,b))

for i in range(2,n):
    l = train_ds[i][0].reshape(1,1,28,28)
    c = torch.cat((c,l))
    
        

train_lables = torch.tensor(d)
```

**it took (10-15 mins)**

Answer (score 0):

In certain languages, repeatedly concatenating arrays on top of each other tends to be slow. If you know the dimensions of your data array, you can pre-allocate the memory to speed up the process.

I can't exactly help with the specifics because I don't know the shape of train_ds, but the optimization might look something like this:

```py
n = len(train_ds)

# I'm not sure if this is the actual shape you need
# Adjust according
c = torch.zeros((n, 1, 28, 28)) 
for i in range(0, n):
    c[i] = train_ds[i][0].reshape(1,1,28,28)
```

Also an alternative way of declaring your `d` array is to call like this:

```py
d = [train_ds[i][1] for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

What nablag said.

it's better if you know the shape beforehand, but if you don't, that can be dealt with like so:

```
c = torch.tensor([
    image.reshape(1,1,28,28)
    for (image, label) in train_ds
])
d = [label for (image, label) in train_ds]
```

you pass a python list to `torch.tensor`. you can build the list like so (list comprehension) or you can start with an empty list `[]` and `.append` to it, then pass it to `torch.tensor`.

also note how I iterate over `train_ds`. you don't need to mess around with indices at all.